# Can I run Appium tests from Cloud-based mobile application test service provider?

Tags: browserstack, saucelabs, aws-device-farm, perfecto, kobiton

I am super confused about the cloud-based mobile application test providers. Do they only provide mobile devices that I can provision? It appears after provisioning we have to run tests manually.

Or they also provide the functionality to run tests on those mobile devices. For example, my tests are written in Robot Framework and Appium. Can I run those tests in the Cloud-based mobile application test service provider like AWS Device Farm, Kobiton, or Sauce Labs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BrowserStack to run your test on. You might want to refer the below links for more details on how to run it.

https://medium.com/detesters/integrating-robot-framework-with-browserstack-bddf5b0e0c14

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/getting-started/python

For mobile devices that you wish to choose, you can refer from the below link.

https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities